# How utilize user input later in another method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

For the following, I'm having a difficult time understanding how to use my user input from (days) and utilizing it on the last line to calculate the # of hours and minutes based on the user input of (days).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LearnScanner {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        first();
        next();
        third();
    }
    public static void first() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Vacation Planner!!");
        System.out.print("What is your name?");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Nice to meet you "+name +", where are you travelling to?");
        String destination = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Great! "+destination +" sounds like a great trip");
     }
    public static void next() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many days are you going to spend travelling?");
        String days = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("How much money in USD are you planning to spend on your trip?");
        String budget = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("What is the three letter currency symbol for your travel destination?");
        String currency = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("How many " + currency + " are there in 1 USD?");
        String currencyConversion = input.nextLine();
    }
    public static void third() {
        String days;
        String hours = days * 24;
        String minutes = hours * 60;

        System.out.println("If your are travelling for " + days + " days that is the same as " + hours + " hours or " + minutes + " minutes");
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you do it the way you're currently doing it? If you're getting an error, please share the error message.

Comment: Error(36,28) java: '.class' expected                                               
Error(36,33) java: not a statement                                                                        * Line 36 is:  String hours = days * 24;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `next()` method return `String`, not void.

```
public static String next() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many days are you going to spend travelling?");
    String days = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("How much money in USD are you planning to spend on your trip?");
    String budget = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("What is the three letter currency symbol for your travel destination?");
    String currency = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("How many " + currency + " are there in 1 USD?");
    String currencyConversion = input.nextLine();
    return days;
}
```

And then in your `third()` method change the following line of code:

```
String days;
```

with

```
int days = Integer.valueOf(next());
```

Change also the next two lines of code with the following:

```
int hours = days * 24;
int minutes = hours * 60;
```

Comment: That fixed it!  Thank you!   One more question, when I get to the "String hours = days * 24;" it is now giving an error of:  java: bad operand types for binary operator "*"  first type: java.lang.String second type: int     ++ I'm assuming I have a simple mathematical error in the way I have set up the code line?

Comment: Ran without errors this time!  However, it repeated the next() method before proceeding to the last.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it seems that the program shouldn't even compile successfully.
The object 'days' in third() is of String type. It isn't possible to multiply a String object with a numeric value 24. Ditto for minutes and hours on the next line as well.

Also, 'days' is being accepted in next() and as such is a local variable. It does not hold any significance in third().

Perhaps this might help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LearnScanner
{
    static String days = null;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        first();
        next();
        third();
    }

    public static void first()
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Vacation Planner!!");
        System.out.print("What is your name?");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Nice to meet you " + name + ", where are you travelling to?");
        String destination = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Great! " + destination + " sounds like a great trip");
    }

    public static void next()
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many days are you going to spend travelling?");
        days = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("How much money in USD are you planning to spend on your trip?");
        String budget = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print(
                "What is the three letter currency symbol for your travel destination?");
        String currency = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("How many " + currency + " are there in 1 USD?");
        String currencyConversion = input.nextLine();
    }

    public static void third()
    {

        String hours = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(days) * 24);
        String minutes = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(hours) * 60);

        System.out.println(
                "If your are travelling for " + days + " days that is the same as "
                        + hours + " hours or " + minutes + " minutes");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you!   This seems logical to me now.  However, after making the suggested edits, I get the following error:    java: cannot find symbol      symbol:  variable days        locations:  class LearnScanner